# Fiware Cygnus PostgreSQL sink does not create table when entity id contains special characters

Tags: postgresql, fiware, fiware-cygnus

It appears that *cygnus-ngsi* and its PosgreSQL sink can't create a postgres table when the entity has an id that contains the `-` chracter, e.g. `urn:ngsi-ld:Motion:001` as recommended in [the Fiware tutorials](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/#entity-ids-should-be-a-urn-following-ngsi-ld-guidelines).

I setup a simple stack with Orion, an IoT-Agent as well as Cygnus-NGSI and a PostgreSQL database.

However, PostgreSQL reports the error

```
2020-11-10 08:39:33.404 UTC [66] ERROR: syntax error at or near "-" at character 44
2020-11-10 08:39:33.404 UTC [66] STATEMENT: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS openiot.urn_ngsi-ld_motion_001_thing (recvTimeTs text,recvTime text,fiwareServicePath text,entityId text,entityType text,attrName text,attrType text,attrValue text,attrMd text)
```

The error does not occur when a different entity id is used.
Data is then persisted as expected.

Cygnus [should replace non-alphanumeric characters inentity ids with `_`](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/200#issuecomment-56508483), however, that does not appear to be happening.
Is this just a bug or do I need some sort of [name mapping](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/name_mappings.md#case-7-groups-maching-service-entitytype-attribute-name-and-attribute-type-in-the-same-tableprefix-depending-on-entityid) to solve this?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a coding/development question. Could you raise this as an [issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues) in the relevant GitHub project instead?

Comment: Sure, however, Stackoverflow was the [recommended way](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/reporting_issues_and_contact.md) to report issues. I just created [#1977](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/1977).

Comment: An answer has been provided in SOF here, although we can use the #1977 issue to discuss possible Cygnus evolutions regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Looking to [encoding section in the Postgresql sink documentation](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/master/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_postgresql_sink/index.html#about-the-encoding) it seems no special encoding is done for `-`.

Thus, `-` progresses as it is to Postgresql table creation logic and raises an error, due to it is forbidden in table names by the database.

You can explore the name mappings option (although I'm not sure if you can change entity ids using it...). Another possible workaround (pretty simple) is not using `-` in entity ids, e.g: `urn:ngsild:Motion:001`